# Lua string concatenation in Json blob

Tags: lua

I have a question about string concatenation.

I have this example where I am trying to append a value inside a json block with a variable value

example:

```
clock = os.clock()
body = "{\"name\":\"stringValue\" .. clock }"
print(body)
```

When I run this I get the following output:

```
{"name":"stringValue" .. clock }
```

What I am expecting is something like

```
{"name":"stringValue0.010117"}
```

How do I make is so this variables value is added to the string?

Comment: Try `"{\"name\":\"stringValue\"" .. clock .. "}"` instead. You have to *end* a string before the concatenation operator.

Answer (score 3):

This is an instance were using [`[[` `]]` delimited strings](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.1) is useful:

```
clock = os.clock()
body = [[{"name":"stringValue]] .. clock .. [["}]]
print(body)
```

To continue using a double quoted string, your variable assignment would look like the following (note how the quote after `stringValue` is not escaped):

```
body = "{\"name\":\"stringValue" .. clock .. "\"}"
```

Comment: Single quotes would work here as well. Also you failed to address the crucial change to the OPs code that makes this work (you made the change and fixed the problem you just didn't mention it at all).